# How to delete ListView Items by ID

Tags: android, android-listview, position

I'm trying to delete the items in my ListView by their ID. Currently they are being deleted by the first position on the List. I can have many items in the list.(example) When I try to delete the sixth item from the list the first item is deleted and the sixth remains.
How do I get the List to delete by ID like in this case m1aa or stringl1. My database deletes stringl1 perfectly but it remains in the list unless it's in the top position.

```
int pos; 
long id;
final ListView lv = getListView();
```

I forgot to add this to my question

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
R.layout.singlelistview,listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Sorry

```
Button button5 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {

TextView textviewlay1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.m1aa);
String stringl1 = textviewlay1.getText().toString();
Double doubl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringl1);


final String str=lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick string=" + str);
{listItems.remove(pos);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
controller1.deletename(stringl1);
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because getView() called for all the items then you click on button to delete row at that time position is set to last row thats why last item is deleted every time. You have to set position as tag to button and on the time of deletion you can get index by this tag. Thanks

```
int pos; 
long id;
final ListView lv = getListView();

Button button5 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
button5.setTag(pos);
button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {

TextView textviewlay1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.m1aa);
String stringl1 = textviewlay1.getText().toString();
Double doubl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringl1);


final String str=lv.getItemAtPosition((Button)v.getTag()).toString();
Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick string=" + str);
{listItems.remove(String.vauleOf((Button)v.getTag()));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
controller1.deletename(stringl1);
}});
```

It can also be done through onItemClickListener

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
          int position, long id) {
        final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                list.remove(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

    });
```

Comment: ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; It's saying The method getItemAtPosition(int) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (Button). is there something I need to my ArrayAdapter.

Comment: It seems that you are not initializing your ArrayAdapter and setting adapter to the list. ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter); if yes i need your full code

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you do not set variable `pos`.It is an `int` variablae,so it is 0 when you call:

```
listItems.remove(pos);
```

And as result first item(that it's index is equal to 0) will be deleted.